# Initializing data member of struct in C++

Tags: c++, functor

//Not able to figure out how we can initialize data member of an struct inside 
//struct . I believe this is against the guidelines of OOP . The below program is not showing any compiler error and runs fines and gives output 10  30

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Accumulator
{
    int counter = 0;
    int operator()(int i) { return counter += i; }
};
int main(void)
{
   Accumulator acc;
   cout << acc(10) << endl; //prints "10"
   cout << acc(20) << endl; //prints "30"
}
```

Comment: Don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 1):

The rules regarding in class initialization have changed.  Starting in C++11 you can initialize a non static class member directly in the class body.  This is just syntactic sugar though.  When you write

```
struct Accumulator
{
    int counter = 0;
    int operator()(int i) { return counter += i; }
};
```

The compiler will actually add the initialization of counter to the default constructor.  So the above code would get translated to

```
struct Accumulator
{
    int counter;
    Accumulator() : counter(0) {}
    int operator()(int i) { return counter += i; }
};
```

This initialization is also suppressed if you supply your own initialization.  If we had

```
struct Accumulator
{
    int counter = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    Accumulator() {}
    Accumulator(int counter) : counter(counter) {}
    int operator()(int i) { return counter += i; }
};
```

Then `Accumulator() {}` would actually be

```
Accumulator() : counter(0), sum(0) {}
```

and `Accumulator(int counter) : counter(counter) {}` would be

```
Accumulator(int counter) : counter(counter), sum(0) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's done with the *constructor*, to which you can pass the initial value.

Something like:

```
struct Accumulator
{
    Accumulator(int initial = 0)
        : counter(initial)
    {}

    int counter;

    int operator()(int i) { return counter += i; }
};

int main(void)
{
    Accumulator acc(20);
    std::cout << acc(10) << '\n'; //prints "30"
    std::cout << acc(20) << '\n'; //prints "50"

    // Reset accumulator
    acc = Accumulator();  // Use constructors default argument
    std::cout << acc(10) << '\n'; //prints "10"
    std::cout << acc(20) << '\n'; //prints "30"
}
```

---

If you wonder why it's working without the constructor too, that's because the structure without a constructor is an *aggregate* and you can use [*aggregate initialization*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

If you wonder about the initialization of the `counter` member, it's because it's a [non-static data member](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members) and since the C++11 standard those can be [initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) like that.

Comment: boss even without constructor its working and that is what my question is , as it should show compiler error as I am initializing data member inside struct

Comment: @user3798283 Updated my answer.